# Rendering a list of optional components in React

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have some optional components that need to be rendered based on user's preferences. I get a list of these components and their order in an array from a call to my API.

The array will look like this:

```
[
   { "id": 23, "name": "WhetherComponent", "label": "Local Whether", "displayOrder": 1 },
   { "id": 477, "name": "NFLComponent", "label": "NFL Results", "displayOrder": 2 },
   { "id": 59, "name": "NBAComponent", "label": "NBA Results", "displayOrder": 3 }
]
```

And in the parent component, I need to render them within `<div>` tags. Clearly, I need to import these components in the parent component but is there anything special I need to do to render them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`lazy()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) to achieve this:

```js
render() {
  return this./*state? props?*/.yourArray.map(ele => {
    const Comp = React.lazy(() => import('./' + ele.name));
    return <div><Comp /></div>; // You said you need to render them within <div>s
  });
}
```

Of course, you might want to `sort()` the array based on `displayOrder` beforehand.

Comment: Thank you! The only issue I had was the lazy loading as it looks like `React.lazy()` was introduced in version 16.6 and mine is older than that. I was still able to do a straight `import` and use it though. Thanks.